# efficient matrix power in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am stuck in finding a way to implement an MATLAB function "Pow(A,k)" that 
raises the matrix A to the power k using only basic linear algebra operations (like Matrix-vector or matrix-matrix multiplications).

The implementation must be efficient, I couldn't find a way to do it in O(n^2), is it even possible?

The only thing I know is that we might want to use the MATLAB function "de2bi" that extracts the binary digits of an integer

Comment: Why can't you use `B = A^k;`?

Comment: well, the purpose of the assignement is to program our own. Of course we can then compare the efficiency of the implementation with Matlab's " ^ " operator

Comment: If it's homework I'll just give you hints: use the [matrix decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Decomposition) and then take the power of the diagonal.

Comment: n is the dimension of the Matrix, A is an nxn Matrix

Comment: sadly we are not allowed to use matrix decomposition, just basic operator like Matrix-vector / Matrix-Matrix

Comment: Well, then you certainly can't do it in O(n^2)...

Comment: Check the duplicate post.  The post essentially uses a loop and multiplies `A` with itself `n` times... achieving `A^n`.  However, the question is slightly different because the question is storing each power in every iteration of the loop as a slice into a 3D matrix, but this essentially does what you want... and it's quite fast.  You only need to remember the last result and so if you ignore the intermediate storing and look at the final resulting matrix, the code will run even faster.  Never discount loops outright.  You'd be surprised how fast they perform given certain situations.

Comment: BTW, there's no way you achieve what you want in `O(n^2)` time.  Brute-force matrix multiplication is `O(n^3)`, but [Strassen's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) can achieve this in roughly `O(n^2.8)` time.  This is just for one matrix multiplication.  Doing this with a matrix power will certainly not give you anything less.

Comment: @rayryeng [Coppersmith–Winograd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm) `O(n^2.3)`.

Comment: @IKavanagh - oi thanks!... still not `O(n^2)` though :(

Comment: @rayryeng Nope, not yet...

Comment: thanks, do you see any way to use the de2bi function ?

Comment: @Phil - Why do you want to use the `de2bi` function?

Comment: I don't know, just a tip that was given to us

Comment: I don't really see how it can be used and why... unless you're not telling us the whole story.

Comment: I'll inform you when I get the answer then

Comment: @Phil You could do `k = bi2de(de2bi(k))` and then whatever other method you want for computing `A^k` but I digress.

Comment: The problem with the iterative method discussed above is that k iterations are needed and k could be large. I just want to point out that there are more efficient ways eg. based on the Cayley Hamilton theorem. Also if your matrix is diagonal or at least diagonalisable the solution is much simplier. Also the iterative method above doesn't handle cases where 'k' is not integer etc.

Answer (score 0):

C = mpower(A,B) is an alternate way to execute A^B, but is rarely used. It enables operator overloading for classes.

Comment: thanks but I need to implement my own function and not use one of Matlab's :)

Comment: `function [  C ] = my_matrix_mult( A,B )
[m,n]=size(A);
[k,l]=size(B);
if(n~=k)
    C=[];
    disp('Error, not able to multiply matrices');
    return
end
C=zeros(m,1);
       for i=0:m;
        for j=0:l;
            for p=0:n;
                flag=1;
                C(i,j)=C(i,j)+ A(i,p)*B(p,j);
            end            
        end
    end
end`

Comment: You can easily just do `A*B`.  Don't write loops for the multiplication when MATLAB can do that natively.

Comment: @PrashantItaliya You shouldn't put that much code in a comment. It would be better to add it to the answer, then you could come back and ping the OP in a comment.

Comment: this code is for multiplication of 2 matrix. if you want to do it for power, you can use for look according to your work.

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, but update the answer instead. Reading 3 continuous lines is not very convenient.

Comment: That code will give you an indexing error.  MATLAB starts indexing at 1, not 0.  What's the purpose of the `flag` variable?